# Passing data from activity to fragment - how to?

Tags: android

I want to pass the Users data (name, username, email) from the Login activity to a fragment. I already searched for an answer and found out I had to work with bundles. This is what I got so far.

Here is where I save the data in a bundle.

*LoginActivity*

```
Bundle bundleUserData = new Bundle();
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
bundleUserData.putString("fullname", fullnameFromDB);
bundleUserData.putString("username", usernameFromDB);
bundleUserData.putString("email", emailFromDB);
fragment.setArguments(bundleUserData);
```

Here is where I try to retrieve the data. *I had to make that IF statement to get rid of a NPE*.

*Fragment*

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
    String strFullname = getArguments().getString("fullname");
    String strUsername = getArguments().getString("username");
    String strEmail = getArguments().getString("email");

    gebruikersnaam.setText(strUsername);
    txtEmail.setText(strEmail);
    txtFullname.setText(strFullname);
}
```

For some reason, the Textviews are not set with the string in which the data is stored.

Can anyone see a problem here?

Comment: I got it to work with SharedPreference, but is this the best way? When to use Bundle and when SharedPreference?

Comment: For sharing data from activity to activity or activity to fragments or fragments to fragments, Bundle is one best practice SharedPref is not a good choice here. But for the store, some values like username or login session shared preferences are best.

Comment: Can you show the code in the login activity where you add/replace HomeFragment and where do you put the code to retrieve data in HomeFragment?

Comment: @SonTruong to retrieve --> oncreate. To add/replace -> onclicklistener

Comment: Does your code in the fragment go to if block?

Comment: @SonTruong Sorry, what do you mean exactly? It's inside an if statement under oncreateview

Comment: I mean when you debug the app, make sure the value of `strFullname`, `strUsername`, `strEmail` is not empty first.

Answer (score 0):

You must first put getArgument in a bundle in your fragment. Try this please:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
String myValue = bundle.getString("message");
```

Comment: Not working.. Did I pass the data correct in the login activity ?

Comment: @dub could you please debug your app and see if your variables getting their values?